# QML can't anchor to item in layout

Tags: qt, qml

Observe this quick example:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 100
    height: 100

    Label {
        text: "foobar"

        anchors.bottom: row.top
        anchors.left: label1.right
    }

    RowLayout {
        id: row
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        width: parent.width

        Label {
            id: label1
            text: "hello1"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        }
        Label {
            id: label2
            text: "hello2"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
        }
    }
}
```

I have two items in row layout, and I want to anchor the third label to one of them. This is what i get:
[image: foobad]

I expect foobar to be more to the right, but it's not what I get.

Also with this any margins I set to the label will be ignored too.

I can anchor to window or to RowLayout and it would work nicely, but for some reason I can't anchor to items inside the layout. What's the reason and what's the appropriate solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile the program you will get the error: `Cannot anchor to an item that isn't a parent or sibling.` Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40128852/cannot-anchor-to-an-item-that-isnt-a-parent-or-sibling-qml-qtquick), why you can't anchor. My solution in, that we will anchor to the left of **row** and then make margin with width of the **label1** inside the row.

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 100
    height: 100

    Label {
        color: "#b7087d"
        text: "foobar"

        anchors.bottom: row.top
        anchors.left: row.left
        anchors.leftMargin: label1.width
    }

    RowLayout {
        id: row
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        width: parent.width

        Label {
            id: label1
            color: "#b22424"
            text: "hello1"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        }
        Label {
            id: label2
            color: "#1e62ce"
            text: "hello2"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that anchoring feature. Well, margins are not the that convenient, so I think I'll rethink the whole layout.